# Not getting default Value of the parameter while running Jmeter Script from Non-GUI Mode

Tags: regex, csv, jmeter

I have used CSV file in jmeter script but due to some error it is not picking up values from csv file. So I used regular Expression extractor to have default values set for variables. When running script in GUI mode, It is picking up default values i.e "Dubai, United Arab Emirates". But when I am running script in Non-GUI mode

`jmeter -n -t /home/data/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/test.jmx -l /home/data/apache-jmeter-3.2/bin/Results/full.jtl`

I am not getting Default values but "Id" text ?

[image: Jmeter Script][image: Non GUI-Mode[![Logs]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpwnl.png)

Comment: in `CSV Data Set Config` did you set ignore first line as true?

Comment: No I have Set it "False". I am getting error as `2018-05-08 16:39:44,371 WARN o.a.j.f.FileRowColContainer: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hotelcitycountry.csv (No such file or directory)` for CSV File

Comment: from your last comment sounds like you re referring to CSV data set by relative path and that's failing in non-gui mode. Best is to use absolute path, but if you want to use relative path, you need to `cd` into the same directory you are in while in interactive mdoe.

Comment: @KirilS. Thanks, my problem is solved by using Absolute Path for CSV. But issue is that I have my csv file in `bin` folder and script also in `bin` folder still not picking up CSV file.